# Mongo $sample fails on some machines

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

On dev machine, a `$sample` query works fine. 
On production machine it fails.

It's a very simple query to get some random elements from a collection.
No other agg pipeline commands.

Any suggestions where to look?
Goog turned up a couple of other issues but nothing much.

- dev machine: Mac v3.6.5
- prod machine: Ubuntu v3.6.7
- error:

`$sample stage could not find a non-duplicate document after 100 while using a random cursor`

code:

```
let grams = await GramsModel.coll.aggregate(
  [
    { $sample: { size: 2 } }
  ]
).toArray()
```

log

```
@random.rikai-bots.com 279|tutorw | MongoError: $sample stage could not find a non-duplicate document after 100 while using a random cursor. This is likely a sporadic failure, please try again.
@random.rikai-bots.com 279|tutorw |     at Function.MongoError.create (/opt/rikai/web-apps/tutorweb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/error.js:31:11)
@random.rikai-bots.com 279|tutorw |     at queryCallback (/opt/rikai/web-apps/tutorweb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:212:36)
@random.rikai-bots.com 279|tutorw |     at /opt/rikai/web-apps/tutorweb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:469:18
@random.rikai-bots.com 279|tutorw |     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
@random.rikai-bots.com 279|tutorw | Mon, 08 Oct 2018 20:00:33 GMT server
```

The error is NOT sporadic - 100% happens on Ubuntu/3.6.7 and never on Mac/3.6.5

Else I just have to write my own get random items func using offsets or something...

Comment: This only happen when the cursor return duplicate documents after 100 attempts. [Source here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/b7ff5816f4d9d468b1875013384e7e51184628a0/src/mongo/db/pipeline/document_source_sample_from_random_cursor.cpp#L103-L144)

Comment: I wonder how it could be different across envs? I did also dump and reload the data from prod into my dev env. Could this happen if there is one duplicate record, (except for the _id field)?